# Problems with styling the dropdown-menu in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, dropdown

In Wordpress, I'm trying to style the dropdown menu used in `.primary-menu`. Unfortunately, things don't really go as planned.

I copied the HTML from the inspector in Chrome and removed the clutter such as href's and id's and tried to debug it in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1cL8fq8b/1/

When hovering over the last `item` in the results tab, `.sub-item` seems to take the width of it's parent. I gave `.sub-menu` an absolute position to make it independent. Still I can't get `.sub-item` to have it's own width.
[Here's a screenshot for a better view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK17B.png).

How can I make the sub-item to have it's own width, and not rely on it's parent's width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a negative `margin-left` style to extend your drop down menu to the left.

```
.sub-menu {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        display: none;
        margin-left:-100px;
}
```

See this: https://jsfiddle.net/jokbd6L5/

Or define a custom width for your drop down:

```
.sub-menu {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        display: none;
        width:100px;
}
```

See this: https://jsfiddle.net/hjoctv5x/

Since its position is absolute I don't think there is a way in CSS to make it expand according to the width of its content (variable width). But you can write some javascript to calculate the max content width for each dropdown menu and set the dropdown menu width accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's because on hover its `display` is set to `block`. Set it to `inline-block` instead

Comment: Try to set its width

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost.. read this http://learnlayout.com/position.html

> absolute is the trickiest position value. absolute behaves like fixed except relative to the nearest positioned ancestor instead of relative to the viewport. If an absolutely-positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and still moves along with page scrolling. Remember, a "positioned" element is one whose position is anything except static.

So basically absolute positioning only takes it out of the document flow

also.. this piece of code..

```
&:hover .sub-menu
```

is only targeting the submenu. Try targeting the li of the submenu to give it its own width. the submenu ul (which is what your targeting has nothing to do with the width of the li's unless they are sized based on percentages.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with that selection. What I'm trying to do is to simply show the entire .sub-menu when hovering over it's parent. Why would I want to let all the list-items appear instead of just the entire sub-menu? Do you understand my question?

Comment: Besides, I gave .menu-item a relative position, which should result into the absolute-positioned element to rely on that element. However, it doesn't.

Comment: Well.. Lemme put it this way. Your selection works. What im saying is that your not styling enough. I gave your selection the attributes width:100px; outline:1px solid red; and it clearly takes the width. The problem your having is that your list item (li) won't automatically fill the UL. If you put outline on all your elements this is clearly illustrated. What im suggesting is that your targeting IS ONLY targeting your ul, but you need to style your li elements as well

Comment: also.. your positioning is also working as intended. Read the article i linked in its entirety. You will see that the positioning is working as intended. If your  parent element (.menu-item) was not relative then the absolute positioned element would automatically default to the document body, completely taking it out of the flow of the document.

Comment: if you remove your list-style (list-style:none;) from the UL and set the position of your list item to block or width 100% it will fill as intended fixing your issue.